# How to create triple div border in CSS

Tags: css, border

I want to create the following div border:
[image]
I have the green border part sorted, but not the red line along the top. Any ideas?

Code so far:

```
#myborder {
border: 4px solid green;
}
```

Comment: if I understand correctly - you don't want whole top border red - but green-red-green, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this css http://jsfiddle.net/PESHk/3

```css
#myborder {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px  green, 0 0 0 4px  green inset;
    border-top:2px solid red;
    padding:8px;
}
```

Comment: its showing on all sides open your eyes if you wnat only border top than use this  border-top:2px solid red;

Comment: but question was only for top one with red stripe ;)

Comment: i have updated the link check it i just make a example but now its like what u wanted

Comment: With differently coloured borders, the ends of the red line will have wrong shape (triangle).

Comment: Is there anyway to do this without box-shadow? I'd also like to add  box-shadow: 0px 4px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.15) to show some lighting effect.

Comment: @alias51 You can have multiple box-shadows, just separate them by a comma. Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/PESHk/5/

Answer (score 2):

Working on Hushme's answer: http://jsfiddle.net/PESHk/2/

```
#myborder {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px  green, 0 0 0 4px  green inset;
    border-top: 2px solid red;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

And [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PESHk/7/) by using `::before`:

```
#myborder {
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    border: 8px solid green;
    border-top: 0;
    padding: 16px 8px 8px 8px;
    position: relative;
}

#myborder::before {
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    height: 2px;
    border: 4px solid green;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;  
}
```